# Start spesific app preventing Intent chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have declared custom action for `Intent` and built the UI based on applications which can handle that `Intent`. Now that I know which application the button click should start, how to prevent the chooser from showing all possible applications.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager
        .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < activities.size(); i++) {
    final ResolveInfo info = activities.get(i);

    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(info.loadLabel(packageManager));

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // This line was the solution
            intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    mLayout.addView(b);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please allow the *user* to choose which one of the *user's* apps on the *user's* device is used to fulfil the *user's* request to work with the *user's* data, using the *user's* battery, bandwidth, and so on.

Comment: @CommonsWare, and using the *user*'s in-app billing app? [In-app billing could be easily hacked](https://sufficientlysecure.org/index.php/2013/10/29/google-play-billing-hacked/) due to a missing line, `bindIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending")`, that restricted IAB handling. Same kind of thing could happen here (although unlikely, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Intent.setPackage(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29), which allows you to make an Intent start only with the provided package name, thus bypassing the chooser. If the package you want to use is not natively present on Android, I still advise you to check its presence at first, and alert the user otherwise.